# How to use prepareForSegue and avoid errors when using pushViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, pushviewcontroller

My segues were added in the storyboard.  I want push to a viewController, say Deep_VC, different from the next one in the storyboard, say Next_VC.  I'm using:

```
Deep_VC *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DeepVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

It goes there, but I get errors.  The nav bar tile is for the Next_VC, not the Deep_VC, and the error messages:

```
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state . . .
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions . . .
```

My prepareForSegue looks like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toNextVC"]) {
        Next_VC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.receivedData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:passData, nil];
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toDeepVC"]) {
        Deep_VC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.receivedData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:passData, nil];
    }
}
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use performSegue instead of pushViewController in your case. But wait, if you`ve wired your VCs in the storyboard you don't need to push. This will be done automagically by the segue.

**EDIT**

```
if (login == successful) {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNextVC" sender:self];
} else {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDeepVC" sender:self];
}
```

After that prepareForSegue will be called automatically and there you set your data. pushViewController is not needed as the seque pushes the appropriate VC.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but the Deep_VC push is conditioned by code not in the storyboard and not in a VC that has the segue I need.

Comment: How does the user trigger the segue or push?

Comment: OK, means no user interaction in the interface. Then i'd use perform segue. Please look at my edited answer.

Comment: I really appreciate the follow-up, but, without more changes, the Deep segue identifier isn't found.

Comment: In the storyboard is there set the right custom class in the class field in the inspector? Could you please post a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: My reputation is too weak to post images. There are about a dozen VCs in it.  Every VC has a custom class.  The more I look at this, the more I want to use your suggestion.  I now know that pushViewController bypasses the prepareForSegue, so my variables aren't passed.  That's a problem.

Comment: Exactly. Thats why you need to use performSegue if you want to trigger outside of a button in the interface. pushViewController is a complete different way. Anyway you could instantiate a ViewController and set the variables in the VC instance and then push it. Works as well. But mixing segue and push i never tried.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.  I added a button to my pushing VC so that I could add a new, direct segue to the DeepVC.  It works.  No errors.  Really appreciate your help, rockstarberlin.  Not as elegant as I imagined, but I need to move forward.